# event not firing in meteor js template in infowindow when using google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor, meteor-blaze

```
 var infoWindowData={
                name : document.name,
                title : document.title
            };

            var siteInfoWindowContent =Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.infoWindowContent, infoWindowData);
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infoWindow.setContent(siteInfoWindowContent);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.open(map.instance, marker);
            });

            <template name="infoWindowContent">
            <button>Click Me!</button>
            </template>

           Template.infoWindowContent.events({
               'click .button':function(event){
                   console.log('clicked a button')
               }
           });
```

When i click on the button nothing happens. toHTMLWithData appears to only return a string and loses the connection to the template.infowindowContent.events code, any idea what could be used instead?

Comment: `.button` is a class selector. Get rid of the period to use it as a tag selector `click button`

Comment: that did not work :-(

Comment: I've never tried to use the native Blaze functions to render HTML like this, but my guess is that since the HTML is being attached to the DOM by the info window code the template events won't work. You'll probably have add an ID to the button and use good old jQuery or getElementById to attach an event handler.

Comment: Hey Brian, you are most definitely correct. i stopped using InfoWindows altogether